# "Review" UI does not reflect close vote limit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, review, vote-to-close

The UI on https://stackoverflow.com/review/ does not indicate that you are out of close votes in the way it indicates other limits being hit. Indicators that should be made:

- *Close Votes* section should be grayed out and moved to the bottom.
- The "Close" button in *Low Quality Posts* reviews should be disabled or hidden.
- Message stating "Thank you for submitting X close votes today" should be displayed when this limit is reached via the *Close Votes* (and possibly the *Low Quality Posts*) UI, consistent with that message for other limits.

Minor issue.

Comment: Hey! It's doing it now! Was that just changed, or did I miss something yesterday?

Comment: Bump for the second point (*The "Close" button in Low Quality Posts reviews should be disabled or hidden*).